# Como controlar o carregamento de CSSs usando Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

O plugin RequireJS é capaz de controlar a importação de scripts sem a necessidade de explicitá-los no html com a tag `<script>`. Isso traz vantagens como controle de dependências e ordem de importação.

[Porém o RequireJS não foi desenvolvido para controlar arquivos CSS.](https://requirejs.org/docs/faq-advanced.html#css)

A minha pergunta é: existe uma forma (**tão elegante quanto o RequireJS**) de ter esse controle sem a necessidade de explicitamente linkar os arquivos CSS diretamente no html?

Comment: [requrie-css](https://github.com/guybedford/require-css) veja se essa funciona.

Comment: SHOW! Era exatamente disso que eu estava falando! Obrigado!!!